# A mysterious function

Tags: functions

So, let $f$ be a function mapping the positive integer to the positive integer.
Assume that the function $f$ has these properties:

> (1) $f(2)=2$,
>
> (2) $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$,
>
> (3) $f(m)>f(n)$ for $m>n$.

What can we say about $f(1983)$ and more generally about $f(n)$ ?

Comment: What can *you* say about $f(1)$?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you edit your question to show us what you have done so far and where you are stuck and, perhaps, where the question comes from, you are more likely to get answers.

Comment: Can you find one function that satisfies the requirements?

Comment: If the function is known to be uniquely determined by these conditions, then by inspection $f(n)=n$.

Answer (score 2):

By strong induction you can show that for all $n$: $f(n)=n$

Base: Note that $2=f(2)=f(2\cdot 1) = f(2)\cdot f(1) = 2 \cdot f(1)$, and so $f(1)=1$. And $f(2)=2$

Step:

Inductive Hypothesis: For any $k<n$ we have that $f(k)=k$

Now consider $f(n)$. 
Two cases: $n$ is even or $n$ is odd.

If $n$ is even, then $n=2m$ for some integer $m$, and since $m <n$ we have by inductive hypothesis that $f(m)=m$.

Therefore $$f(n)=f(2m)=f(2)\cdot f(m) = 2 \cdot f(m) = 2m = n$$

If $n$ is odd, then $n=2m+1$ for some integer $m$ where $m < n$ and where $m+1<n$, and hence by inductive hypothesis $f(m)=m$ and $f(m+1)=m+1$.

Therefore, $$f(2m)=f(2)\cdot f(m)=2m$$

Also, $$f(2m+2)= f(2(m+1))=f(2)f(m+1)=2(m+1)$$

But we have that $$f(2m)<f(2m+1)<f(2m+2)$$ and so $$2m<f(2m+1)<2m+2$$ and since this is a function from integers to integers, it must be that $$f(n)=f(2m+1)=2m+1=n$$

Answer (score 1):

By $(1)$ and $(2)$, it is easy to see that $f(1)=1$.

Then by strong induction,

- if $\forall m<2n, f(m)=m$, then by $(2)$, $$f(2n)=2f(n)=2n,$$ and
- if $\forall m<2n+1, f(m)=m$, then by $(2)$ and $(3)$, $$2f(n)=2n<f(2n+1)<2f(n+1)=2n+2.$$

So for all integers, $f(n)=n$. The base cases $f(1)=1,f(2)=2$ are sufficient.